# Matrix-vector product with dgemm/dgemv

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, lapack, blas

Using Lapack with C++ is giving me a small headache. 
I found the functions defined for fortran a bit eccentric, so I tried to make a few functions on C++ to make it easier for me to read what's going on.

Anyway, I'm not getting th matrix-vector product working as I wish.
Here is a small sample of the program.

smallmatlib.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>


extern "C"{
    // product C= alphaA.B + betaC                                               
   void dgemm_(char* TRANSA, char* TRANSB, const int* M,
               const int* N, const int* K, double* alpha, double* A,
               const int* LDA, double* B, const int* LDB, double* beta,
               double* C, const int* LDC);
    // product Y= alphaA.X + betaY                                               
   void dgemv_(char* TRANS, const int* M, const int* N,
               double* alpha, double* A, const int* LDA, double* X,
               const int* INCX, double* beta, double* C, const int* INCY);
   } 

void initvec(double* v, int N){
    for(int i= 0; i<N; ++i){
        v[i]= 0.0;
        }
   }

void matvecprod(double* A, double* v, double* u, int N){ 
    double alpha= 1.0, beta= 0.0;
    char no= 'N', tr= 'T';
    int m= N, n= N, lda= N, incx= N, incy= N;
    double* tmp= new double[N];
    initvec(tmp, N);
    dgemv_(&no,&m,&n,&alpha,A,&lda,v,&incx,&beta,tmp,&incy);
    for(int i= 0; i<N; ++i){
        u[i]= tmp[i];
        }
    delete [] tmp;
    }

void vecmatprod(double* v, double* A, double* u, int N){
    double alpha= 1.0, beta= 0.0;
    char no= 'N', tr= 'T';
    int m= N, n= 1, k= N, lda= N, ldb= N, ldc= N;
    double* tmp= new double[N];
    initvec(tmp, N);
    dgemm_(&no,&no,&m,&n,&k,&alpha,A,&lda,v,&ldb,&beta,tmp,&ldc);
    for(int i= 0; i<N; ++i){ 
        u[i]= tmp[i];
        }
    delete [] tmp;
    }
```

smallmatlib.h:

```
#ifndef SMALLMATLIB_H
#define SMALLMATLIB_H

void initvec(double* v, int N);

void matvecprod(double* A, double* v, double* u, int N);

void vecmatprod(double* v, double* A, double* u, int N);

#endif
```

smallmatlab.cpp:

```
#include "smallmatlib.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 2

int main(){
  double A[SIZE*SIZE]=
    { 1,2,
      3,4 };
  double v[SIZE]= {2,5.2};
  double u[SIZE]= {0,0};
  matvecprod(A,v,u,SIZE);
  printf("%f %f\n",u[0],u[1]);
  vecmatprod(v,A,u,SIZE);
  printf("%f %f\n",u[0],u[1]);
  return 0;
  }
```

Compiling:
    g++ -c smallmatlib.cpp
    g++ smallmatlab.cpp smallmatlib.o -L/usr/local/lib -lclapack -lcblas

Now the function matvecprod is the problem.
With the example matrix A and example vector v, it should produce an output like

```
12.4..    26.8..
```

but instead it prints out

```
2.00..    0.00..
```

I tried to produce the correct result with both dgemm and dgemv, but wasn't able to. I have a hunch that my variables incx and incy do not have correct values, but it's difficult to find an explanation for them that I'd understand.

A smaller problem is that at the moment I can't use them like
    vecmatprod(v,A,v,SIZE)
- that is, I always have to define the vector u, that will hold the result, separately, and call vecmatprod(v,A,u,SIZE). 
Any help would be appreciated.

As a side note, I'm also a beginner at C++, so I appreciate any criticism/suggestion you might have about my code.

Comment: `delete tmp;`  Wrong form of `delete`.  It should be: `delete [] tmp;`  But why go through all this when you could have simply passed `u` to your function?

Comment: Edited that part, didn't help with any of the problems though. Say, if I'm making a transformation for a vector, I noticed that sometimes it would be more convinient to be able just assign v= Av

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the problem is in `incx` value - it should be 1, take a look at [reference](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/da8/dgemv_8f.html).

```
INCX is INTEGER
  On entry, INCX specifies the increment for the elements of
  X. INCX must not be zero.
```

So this value should be used when values of vector `x` is not placed one by one (vector of complex values for example, when you want to use only real part).

Also you can not use `vecmatprod(v,A,v,SIZE)` with `v` as both `x` and `y`. This is because how matrix-vector multiplication works (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for example). You need values of original `x` the whole time to produce correct result. Small example:

```
y = A * x
```

where

```
y = [ y1 y2 ]
A = [ [a11 a12] [a21 a22] ]
x = [ x1 x2 ]
```

And we calculate `y` like this

```
y1 = a11 * x1 + a12 * x2
y2 = a21 * x1 + a22 * x2
```

You can see, that when we calculate `y2` we need `x1` and `x2`, but if you use `x = A * x`(without temporary vector) you will replace `x1` with `y1` thus produce wrong answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is the answer I'm looking for (well, I also had to change the flag to T), and you clarified the use of incx/incy. In the function, I tried to go around that problem by defining the temporary variable, storing result there first. For some reason, it still didn't work like I wanted.

Comment: Fogot about this, indeed you need to changevariable to ``T``. This is because LAPACK functions written in Fortran and thus 2-dimensional arrays are stored by column.